# Why would STContains return null?

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeometry

Why would SQLGeometry.STContains return null when the values being used are not null?

Comment: "Returns null if the SRID of the two geography instances are not the same." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929274.aspx

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But you should put that down below so I can mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Returns `null` if the SRID of the two geography instances are not the same.

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929274.aspx